# Set python3 venv environment variable on windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

In my windows machine I created virtual environment by python native (pyvenv) and problem I facing now is I can't set env variables, if I trying to put something like `setx DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE "project.settings.local"` in activate.bat, nothing happens (`os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]` still returns error, that variable doesn't exists).

So question is, how set these env variables in windows (I mean in activate.bat file)?

Comment: Have you made sure django is installed in the environment?

Comment: `setx.exe` sets the environment variable in the registry and broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message that tells Explorer (and any other top-level window that cares) to reload its environment from the registry. cmd.exe doesn't see this; it's a simple console process that doesn't have a message loop. You'd have to start a new instance of cmd.exe from Explorer. If you want to modify the environment in cmd.exe (and child processes such as python.exe), just use its built-in `set` command instead of `setx.exe`.

Comment: `set` works if I use it directly in cmd, but If I put it in activate.bat - nothing happens. It's a bit annoying everytime I start venv to set vars, especially which holds secret keys.

Comment: Just add the line `set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.local"` to `Scripts\activate.bat`.

Comment: ok, I found that np++ and notepad has different newline symbol, that was my problem. Anyway, thanks.